# Does a stationary point of $f(x, y)$ need to have a zero slope in every direction?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, stationary-point

Does a stationary point of  $f(x, y)$ need to have a zero *slope* in every direction?
If so, then why is it sufficient to show $ $ $ $  $f_x(a, b)=f_y(a, b)=0$ $ $ $ $  to determine that $(a, b)$ is a stationary point of $f(x,y)$?

With that approach, aren't we merely showing that $f(x,y)$ has a zero slope in the $x-$ and $y-$ directions at the point $(a, b)$, as opposed to in all directions at the point $(a, b)$?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, then the gradient at a stationary point must be $0$, yes.

Comment: Sorry, by gradient at (a, b), I meant "slope" of the surface f(x, y) at (a,b).  I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the slope of a function $f$ in the direction represented by vector $v$ is $v \cdot \nabla f$. If at some point $\nabla f=0$ (that is, both $f'_x=0$ and $f'_y=0$), then the slope is $v \cdot 0 = 0$. Thus, if the slope is zero in the $x$ and $y$ directions, it is zero in any direction.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$, then $D_{(a,b)}f\equiv0\iff\nabla f(a,b)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, by gradient at (a, b), I meant "slope" of the surface f(x, y) at (a,b). I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I understand it now.  I was missing the actually definition of a **slope**, which is given as

$f_x(a,b)\cos{\alpha}+f_y(a,b)\sin{\alpha}$

where $\alpha$ is an angle determining the direction of the slope.

Hence, if $f_x(a,b)=f_y(a,b)=0$, then the above expression is also zero, and the slope is indeed zero.

---

Can someone please confirm?